# how to lookup the numbers next to character using python

Tags: python-2.7

this is just part of the long python script. there is a file called aqfile and it has many parameters. I would like to extract what is next to "OWNER" and "NS".

```
Note:
OWNER = text
NS = numbers
```

i could extract what is next to OWNER, because they were just text and i could extract.

```
for line in aqfile.readlines():
            if string.find(line,"OWNER")>0:
                print line
                m=re.search('<(.*)>',line)
                owner=incorp(m.group(1))
break
```

but when i try to modify the script to extract the numbers

```
for line in aqfile.readlines():
            if string.find(line,"NS")>0:
                print line
                m=re.search('<(.*)>',line)
                ns=incorp(m.group(1))
break
```

it doesnt work any more.

Can anyone help me?

this is the whole script

```
#Make a CSV file of datasetnames. pulseprog and, if avaible, (part of) the title
#Note: the whole file tree is read into memory!!! Do not start too high in the tree!!!

import os
import os.path
import fnmatch
import re
import string

max=20000
outfiledesc=0


def incorp(c):
    #Vervang " door """ ,CRLF door blankos
    c=c.replace('"','"""')
    c=c.replace("\r"," ")
    c=c.replace("\n"," ")
    return "\"%s\"" % (c)


def process(arg,root,files):
    global max
    global outfiledesc
    #Get name,expno,procno from the root
    if "proc" in files:
        procno = incorp(os.path.basename(root))
        oneup = os.path.dirname(root)
        oneup = os.path.dirname(oneup)
        aqdir=oneup
        expno = incorp(os.path.basename(oneup))
        oneup = os.path.dirname(oneup)
        dsname = incorp(os.path.basename(oneup))
        #Read the titlefile, if any
        if (os.path.isfile(root + "/title")):
            f=open(root+"/title","r")
            title=incorp(f.read(max))
            f.close()
        else:
            title="" 
        #Grab the pulse program name from the acqus parameter
        aqfile=open(aqdir+"/acqus")
        for line in aqfile.readlines():
            if string.find(line,"PULPROG")>0:
                print line
                m=re.search('<(.*)>',line)
                pulprog=incorp(m.group(1))
                break
        towrite= "%s;%s;%s;%s;%s\n" % (dsname,expno,procno,pulprog,title)
        outfiledesc.write(towrite)



#Main program       
dialogline1="Starting point of the search"
dialogline2="Maximum length of the title"
dialogline3="output CSV file"
def1="/opt/topspin3.2/data/nmrafd/nmr"  
def2="20000"
def3="/home/nmrafd/filelist.csv"
result = INPUT_DIALOG("CSV file creator","Create a CSV list",[dialogline1,dialogline2,dialogline3],[def1,def2,def3])
start=result[0]
tlength=int(result[1])
outfile=result[2]
#Search for procs files. They should be in any dataset.
outfiledesc = open(outfile,"w")
print start
os.path.walk(start,process,"")
outfiledesc.close()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: How does your input file look? You are looking for `<>`, but your example does not show those. How do those lines _really_ look?

Comment: My guess: It has nothing to do with the match, but instead `aqfile` is a file iterator and that's exhausted after the first loop.

Comment: Hi tobias, i have added the full script, can you give tips now? Thanks in advance.